# How to Generate/Read BYOK-Compatible Certificate from Apex code

Tags: platform-encryption, shield-encryption, financialforce, shield

How can we read BYOK Compatible certificates present in Salesfoce using Apex (or SF REST APIs). Also is there any way to generate BYOK Compatible certificate using Apex code or SF REST APIs.

I referred below link but it only talks about creating tenant secret using REST api.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_encryption_rest_api_guide.meta/platform_encryption_rest_api_guide/api_rest_encryption.htm#overview

## EDIT:

I am able to fetch other metadata like "ApexClass" using below code. However, for certificate getting error INVALID_TYPE.
(using package mentioned by Chuck: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();                  
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();

queryWorkflow.type_x = 'ApexClass'; //working
//queryWorkflow.type_x = Certificate//not working

queries.add(queryWorkflow);                    

MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 25);

for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties) {
     System.debug(fileProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Managing the cert can be done via the MetaData API:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm

There isn't a straightforward way to do that with Apex.  You might be able to hack it out using the FinancialForce package:  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Thanks Chuck for reply. I tried with examples mentioned by you. However, I am not able to query 'Certificate' info (getting error INVALID_TYPE), but other type are working fine (eg: ApexClass) and I am able to query them.

Comment: @NeerajKukreti If you are trying to SOQL query, `Certificate` is not considered as an `SObject` type, unlike `ApexClass`. Chuck's point is that the data is technically accessible through an API, but not native to Apex.

Comment: @TheSFDCTower I am using FinancialForce package mentioned by Chuck but still not able to fetch certificate info. I have updated my question with snippet I am using.